# Clarification in Hartshorne II Theorem 8.24 c)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a nonsingular $k$-variety, $Y \subset X$ a nonsingular closed subvariety cut out by ideal sheaf $\mathcal I$. Let $\pi: \widetilde{X} \to X$ be the blowup of $X$ along $\mathcal I$, and $Y' \subset \widetilde{X}$ the subscheme defined by the ideal sheaf

$$\mathcal I' := \pi^{-1}(\mathcal I) \cdot \mathcal O_{\widetilde{X}}$$

From (7.13) on page 183, we know $\mathcal I' \cong \mathcal O_{\widetilde{X}}(1)$. Hartshorne then claims that this implies

$$\mathcal I'/\mathcal I'^2 \cong\mathcal O_{Y'}(1)$$

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the result of pulling the isomorphism $\mathcal I' \cong \mathcal O_{\widetilde{X}}(1)$ back to $Y'$ and then pushing it forward to $\widetilde{X}$ again.  Since $Y'$ is the subscheme defined by $\mathcal{I}'$, pulling back to $Y'$ and then pushing forward to $\widetilde{X}$ is the same as tensoring with $\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}/\mathcal{I}'$.  So this sends $\mathcal{I}'$ to $\mathcal{I}'/\mathcal{I}'^2$, and by definition it sends $O_{\widetilde{X}}(1)$ to $O_{Y'}(1)$.